# nl80211 not found:how resolve this error in openwrt

Tags: openwrt

I am doing my project on openwrt router. when i am trying to run "iw list" command it's giving the error like nl80211 not found. even I've installed iw package. what changes I've to make to come outoff this error.

Answer (score 2):

Installing below packages has solved my problem,

- libnl
- libnl-tiny (depends on: libpthread)
- kmod-cfg80211
- kmod-lib80211
  kmod-mac80211 (depends on: kmod-crypto-core, kmod-crypto-arc4,
  kmod-crypto-aes, hostapd-common)
- kmod-mac80211-hwsim

You may try running,

> opkg update
>
> opkg install

If you are offline, download corresponding .ipk files for packages listed above, and then try running,

> opkg install